# Apache Camel split and aggregate exception handling

Tags: apache-camel

We defined a route in Camel with split and aggregate functionality, but can't propagate the exception back to split after the aggregator. Which cause's the split to run even if we encounter an exception

below is the code which is not working

```
from("direct:MyRoute")
     .routeId("MyRouteID")
        .split().tokenize("\n", 1)
        .streaming().stopOnException()
        .choice()
        .when(simple("${property.CamelSplitIndex} > 0"))
           .unmarshal(domainDataFormat)
           .choice()
           .when(simple("${property.CamelSplitComplete}"))
           .process(
              new Processor()
              {
                 @Override
                 public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception
                 {
                    exchange.getIn().getHeaders().put(Exchange.AGGREGATION_COMPLETE_ALL_GROUPS_INCLUSIVE, true);
                 }
              }
           )
           .end()
           .aggregate(myAggregationStrategy).constant(true) //if i comment this line split will be stop on exception
           .threads().executorService(executorService)
           .process(myProcessor).end()
     .end();
```

Processor(myProcessor) from the above code is below:

```
counter.incrementAndGet(); //atomic counter 
if(counter.get()==3)
  {
     exchange.setException(new RuntimeException());
     throw new RuntimeCamelException();
  }
```

But, the moment I remove the aggregate from the route, Split is able to stop the route on Exception.

Answer (score 2):

Use the composite message processor EIP which is split + aggregate (fork/join) in the same unit of work.

See docs at: https://camel.apache.org/components/next/eips/composed-message-processor.html

And see the *splitter only* section where you can specify an aggregation strategy to the splitter to have it work together.

Comment: thanks Claus, for the response. 
as you can check we are using the .streaming and .unmarshal before the aggregate call. 
we can't make that possible with split + aggregate. is there any other way around ?

Comment: You can keep doing that, just remove aggregate and add the agg strategy to the splitter, and you dont need any logic to check for split complete et all. If you got the Camel in Action book read about these patterns there as it has a lot more details

Comment: hi Claus, let me explain how we are using this in our requirement. 
we are processing huge flat fixed length file using the route explained above, so the general flow would be split the file line by line, stream it, then unmarshal to get the POJO out of it(using bindy) aggregate a chunk(on some correlational key)  and the process those chunks in processor(multi-threaded)
But this is not possible with split+ aggregate as it will not help me to do the unmarshal and streaming before aggregate and after split.